# How to remove this character using PHP

Tags: php

I am parsing through text and I came across this character: ... well, apparently I am not able to post a pic but the character is a small outlined box with two rows of very small numbers inside, 00 on the top line and 90 on the bottom. I am sorry I am not able to upload a pic.

However, when I try to insert the character in the following code I get:

```
$essay_result = str_replace("?", "", $essay_result);
```

Instead of:

```
$essay_result = str_replace("the little boxed character", "", $essay_result);
```

How can I write the expression to interpret the symbol so I can strip it from the text?

[image: Here is a pic]
<sub>(source: [imageno.com](http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20150608/jxhlpr476rbe.jpg))</sub>

As far as the text being parsed, it is obviously a close quote:

> Wilma states she â€œsaw the whole thingâ€[the character I am referring to follows here]

Comment: can you show what is there in `$essay_result`? and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: What? Which character? Do you mean: � :)?

Comment: Maybe if we expressed the character as its Hex code it would be clearer.

Comment: Can you identify the char here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: Have you tried setting your default char set to UTF-8?

Comment: If this is character `U+0090`, then you should be able to remove it with `str_replace("\xc2\x90", "", $essay_result);`

Comment: You could try converting your text to ascii  (if you dont mind losing the non-ascii characters throughout your text)   $new_string = utf8_decode($old_string);

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was not able to strip the character (dubbed herein as 'SC') according to user3584460. Since converting to utf turns all the 'â€' related characters into question marks (?), meaning there wont be a way to differentiate between a single quote and a double, I first parsed through all the 'â€™'s and replaced with single quote ('), then 'â€œ's with a dash, so that left no other 'â€'s except the 'â€[SC]', where I then replaced the remaining 'â€'s with a double quote ("), and then converted to utf8, and then replaced all instances of "? with ".

Comment: This will of course delete any other "? where there is a quote with a question mark at the end of a sentence, so it is not a perfect solution. But for my purposes, that is very rare. Thanks again!

Comment: I think that you are mixing the visual representation of text (via fonts) with its in-memory representation and encoding. The fact that you see a question mark or a Euro sign does not mean that that character is in fact a question mark.

Comment: btw, the 'â€œ's were replaced with an opening double quote ("). The 'â€“'s (not previously mentioned) were the ones replaced with a dash (-).

Answer (score 0):

That's a broken character you're showing. Don't just add something to remove the char, find the root cause.

1. make sure all your files use the same encoding(UTF-8 or otherwise)
2. make sure you're not overencoding to another charse
3. make sure you're not outputting anything except where you actually intend to
4. make sure the text you send the browser is actually in the encoding that whatever you are using for storage is in.

If all else fails, go for https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

Best of luck!